# How to know Mongo Collection Data Type?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In Mongo collection data is stored as json with different data type but I want to check all schema bsontype without mentioning the attribute.
that gives the result like - attribute1 - int,   attribute2 - string , attribute - bool

Comment: Where do you want to know it? In C#? Java? Python? UI?

Comment: in mongo DB editor